# Get area or zone name from user's current location (latitude,longitude) in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, area, reverse-geocoding

I am trying to get area or zone from user's current location using reverse geocoding. I am using **GMSGeocoding** but unable to get area name or zone

```
[[GMSGeocoder geocoder] reverseGeocodeCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lng) completionHandler:^(GMSReverseGeocodeResponse* response, NSError* error) {
    NSLog(@"reverse geocoding results:");

   GMSAddress * address=[response firstResult];
    NSLog(@"coordinate.latitude=%f", address.coordinate.latitude);
    NSLog(@"coordinate.longitude=%f", address.coordinate.longitude);
    NSLog(@"thoroughfare=%@", address.thoroughfare);
    NSLog(@"locality=%@", address.locality);
    NSLog(@"subLocality=%@", address.subLocality);
    NSLog(@"administrativeArea=%@", address.administrativeArea);
    NSLog(@"postalCode=%@", address.postalCode);
    NSLog(@"country=%@", address.country);
    NSLog(@"lines=%@", address.lines);
    locationName=address.thoroughfare;
    _txtFromLocation.text= [[locationName stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@",%@",address.locality]]stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@",%@",address.country]];
      }];
```

Please let me know the way I can get the area or zone from user's current location.

[image]

Comment: What you mean with "area name or zone"? there is a locality, subLocality even postalCode, administrative area, and country

Comment: one of them should be what you are looking for

Comment: Unfortunately I am getting null in sublocality and administrative area. Is there any other way to get it.

Comment: Maybe you are getting null because your current location, some locations get null on some GeoCode data try with a well know location example one major city, New York?

Comment: My lat long is not null please see the image of my log.

Comment: I am not saying that your position is nul, I am saying that maybe your location is not well know enough and that is why you don't have all the information, try with NY city location, is in Xcode by default to test, and let me know